# Topology, metric space and finite subsets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Given $E$ is a totally bounded subset of a metric space $X$, I wish to show then for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a finite subset $\{X_l, \ldots ,X_n\}$ of $E$ such that $E \subset \bigcup_{k = 1}^{n} B(x_k, \varepsilon)$.

I know a metric space $X$ is compact if and only if every collection $F$ of closed sets in $X$ with the finite intersection property has a nonempty intersection but this only follows quite trivially from the definition of compactness. Any specific help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint: the definition of totally bounded is that $E$ can be covered by finitely many balls of any radius.

Comment: What is your definition of totally bounded?

Comment: I suppose the general definition is For every r > 0 there is a finite cover of X consisting of balls of radius r?

Comment: Then you're already done, it seems.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma A plausible way of interpreting the question as something not completely trivial is that the definition of total boundedness might have allowed the centers of the balls to be anywhere in $X$ whereas the question wants centers in $E$.

Comment: What are seemingly unrelated X1,. X2,.. X_n?

Comment: They are finite subsets of e, yes I think I am missing a simple link here for centres of the balls in E..